# How to solve a CORS issue with paypal-rest-sdk on react/express local development setup?

Tags: express, cors, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to set up the paypal-rest-sdk in an express server with a react front end, am getting a CORS error. The react server is using a proxy.

I have tried the npm cor() package (couldn't get it to work) and two chrome extension. They stop the error message but nothing else happens either. I don't understand how to use the proper headers...but it seems like one of the other methods should work.

The desired result is to be sent to a paypal pay page.

This code works:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {});

app.post("/pay", (req, res) => {
console.log("you made a successful post request"
});

const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
```

this code works, it logs the payment json object:

```
const express = require("express");
const paypal = require("paypal-rest-sdk");

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {});

paypal.configure({
  mode: "sandbox", 
  client_id:
    "___clientID___",
  client_secret:
    "___clientSECRET___"
});

app.post("/pay", (req, res) => {
  var create_payment_json = {
    intent: "sale",
    payer: {
      payment_method: "paypal"
    },
    redirect_urls: {
      return_url: "http://localhost:3000/success",
      cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/cancel"
    },
    transactions: [
      {
        item_list: {
          items: [
            {
              name: "item",
              sku: "item",
              price: "1.00",
              currency: "USD",
              quantity: 1
            }
          ]
        },
        amount: {
          currency: "USD",
          total: "1.00"
        },
        description: "This is the payment description."
      }
    ]
  };

  paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function(error, payment) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    } else {
console.log(payment)
        }
      }
    }
  });
});

const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
```

But this code breaks it with a CORS error:

```
paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function(error, payment) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
        if (payment.links[i].rel === "approval_url") {
          res.redirect(payment.links[i].href);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

I assume that the res.redirect is the problem.

***EDIT***
I recreated the same express server in a separate project folder, but instead of trying to use it with a React proxy, I created a very simple HTML form to hit '/pay'

This worked, which tells me that the problem is in having react run on localhost:3000 with a proxy to a server that is listening on localhost:5000

SO, the problem is not with PayPal, I can rule that out.

My next step is to learn more about integrating React apps into express...

Any other ideas would be very appreciated!
Thanks!!!

Comment: What’s the exact CORS error message the browser is logging? What’s the URL of the endpoint?

Comment: The docs at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/rest-sdks/ give no indication that PayPal API endpoints are CORS-enabled nor that any of the REST APIs are meant to be used from frontend JavaScript running in a browser. Instead the docs say, *“PayPal provides REST **server** SDKs for these languages: Java, .NET, Node, PHP, Python, Ruby”*.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I believe that the PayPal endpoint is referenced by 

     for (let i = 0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
             if (payment.links[i].rel === "approval_url") {
               res.redirect(payment.links[i].href);

In my sandbox, the href is https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=...

I recreated the code in a more simple fashion, omitting the react side of things, and used a simple HTML form, it worked.

This tells me that the problem is likely from the react proxy. 

I will add this to my original question.

Comment: IE, this tells me that the problem is not with PayPal. I think you already know this, but I guess the problem is that I don't completely understand all of this stuff and am definitely making some noob mistakes. Thanks for your help :)